# How do I install a POM in my local m2 repository?

Tags: maven, installation, pom.xml, parent-pom

I need to install a parent POM (without a JAR file) into my local .m2 repository. `mvn install:install-file` won't let me do that, it always asks for a valid `-Dfile=<path-to-jar>`.

How can I install `tmp/dependency-management-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom`?

Answer (score 47):

While you need to specify `-Dfile`, you can tell `mvn install:install-file` to ignore the file and just install the POM with `-Dpackaging=pom`:

```
mvn install:install-file \
    -Dpackaging=pom \
    -Dfile=tmp/dependency-management-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom \
    -DpomFile=tmp/dependency-management-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

will just install the POM, ignoring the value passed as `file`.

Comment: Note that `file` is *not* ignored! Whatever you specify as `file` will be copied to the `.pom` file in the local repository, e.g. if you specify a `.jar` file the `.pom` file will be binary identical to it. This is at least the case with `maven-install-plugin:3.1.1`.